# Get href list from element list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach

I know I can do this with a simple for loop but I'm trying to understand better how to use `forEach`.

What I'm trying to do is, having a list of "a" elements coming from a querySelectorAll(), to obtain an array with the href attributes. What is wrong?

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
function get_hrefs(links){
    var links_array = links.forEach(function(elem){ return elem.getAttribute("href"); });
    return links_array;
}
get_hrefs(links);
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("a") return a NodeList and not an array

Comment: The error in the web console should be giving you some idea what the first problem is. Any documentation on `forEach` should be giving you an idea what the second problem is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `slice` to get an Array, like this:

```
var links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a"));
var links_array = links.map(function(elem){ return elem.getAttribute("href"); });
```

---

As for the updated question:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

function get_hrefs(links){
    links = Array.prototype.slice.call(links);

    return links.map(function(elem){ return elem.getAttribute("href"); });;
}

get_hrefs(links);
```

Comment: love the answer but, what if the links are given outside the function?

Comment: Such a shame 4 other > 6k users didn't test their code. +1 for being the only one that provides a working answer.

Comment: I updated the example on my answer to be a little more specific about the date I must use, could you check it?

Comment: @Vandervals: Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Just one more thing... in your opinion, support for map is good enough??

Comment: @Vandervals: If you need to support IE8 or similar, it's easily shimmed/polyfilled.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `map` rather than `forEach`, and you need to call it differently because `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, not an arary:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var links_array = Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e){
    return e.getAttribute("href");
});
```

That's if you really want the *attribute value*. If you want the resolved `href`, then:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var links_array = Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e){
    return e.href;
});
```

---

Re your updated question, where the function will receive `links` and not necessarily know what it is: The code above will work both for true arrays and for array-like things like the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll`. So no changes needed to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `foreach`, because `querySelectorAll` doesn't return array so you can do something like this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var links_array = [];
[].forEach.call(
  links, 
  function(elem){
    links_array.push(elem.getAttribute("href"));
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came to this question late — but I believe that this can be achieved in one concise line of code by combining `Array.from` and the `map()` function:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).map(e=>e.href)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var hrefArray = [];
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(elem){ hrefArray.push(elem.getAttribute("href")); });
```

Let `forEach` push the elements into an empty array. forEach just iterates over all the elements. What you do with it is your decision.

Other users are pointing to the use of `map`. That functions suits the problem well. However the question was to get a better understanding of `forEach`.

Cerbrus pointed us to the fact that `querySelectorAll` returns a `nodelist`. Which I overlook at first. instead of an array. Now a `nodelist` is arrayish. So you can still treat it as one by using `Array.prototype.forEach.call()`;

Since `nodelist` doesn't have the function `forEach` we need to invoke it from the Array object. Then we pass a reference to `links` using the first argument of `call`.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` doesn't return an array.